# Why does Isaac glow on spiderwebs?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

In Binding of Isaac: Rebirth, Isaac seems to flash or glow white when he stands on certain floor patterns, such as spiderwebs. Does this mean anything?

[image: GIF of isaac flashing white on spiderwebs]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That glow means that your movement is slowed by the spiderwebs. You see the same effect when walking on white creep such as from the Widow boss and Black creep such as from the Gish boss.